# flexible header that keeps aspect ratio of logo image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to fix the major grid on a website I'm working on right now. 
My goal is to have as little mediaqueries as possible.

I need the Logo-Image to maintain the height of the header and not scale down.

Basically the same for the Timeline-Header, but this one needs also to keep the width of the Timeline.

I tried different solutions, but none seemed to work for me. Might this be time for js? (resize)

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var headerHeight = $('div#header').outerHeight(true)
    var footerHeight = $('div#footer').outerHeight(true);

    var contentHeight = windowHeight - ( footerHeight + headerHeight );
    var contentMargins = $('div#content').outerHeight(true) - $('div#content').height();
    var contentInnerHeight = contentHeight - contentMargins;

    $('div#content').height(contentInnerHeight);
}).resize();
```

So if anyone knows something, that'd be super fantastic. :)

I uploaded a fiddle with the basic grid here: https://jsfiddle.net/hansgohr/62xLfewa/

Also the "full" website can be seen here: http://ocv-2300.net/scrollmagic/
    - here the Timeline-Header works quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain the height of the header image you can use 7.9vh (viewport height) as height on both the header and the header image

```
.logo-space img{
  height:7.9vh;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ullvieib/ty4exd83/

Comment: Tack så mycket! worked perfectly, plus I was able to solve a lot of other issues with it.